# Conversion of a matrix differential equation for rotation to quaternions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, rotations, quaternions

**Specifications and Data**

1. We have a 3D rotation function $R(t)_{3\times 3}$ and function ${K(t)}_{3\times 3}$,  a matrix-valued function that gives skew symmetric matrices as outputs. It has the following form:

$K(t)= \begin{bmatrix}\,0&\!-a_3(t)&\,\,a_2(t)\\ \,\,a_3(t)&0&\!-a_1(t)\\-a_2(t)&\,\,a_1(t)&\,0\end{bmatrix}. \tag 1$ $a_i(s)$  are functions with numerical values, not matrix values unlike the previous case.

2. Let $q(t)$ denote the quaternion of $R(t)$.
3. We have an expression 
   $\frac{\mathrm{d} R(t)}{\mathrm{d}t} = -K(t) R(t).\tag 2$

**Question**

1. **How can we represent the equation(2) in quaternions instead of using 3D rotation matrices? How do we derive that? or else how do we write the equation (2) using $q(t)$ and  $\frac{\mathrm{d} q(t)}{\mathrm{d}t}$.**

NB : I am not implying doubt about how to solve equation(2). I am just seeking to convert it to a quaternion form.

Thanks for taking time to read my question. Any partial answers are also welcome.

Comment: I could write an actual answer, but learning the stuff at the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitesimal_rotation link will have more educational value.

Comment: That link wont help.. I read already.. Here $\kappa(t)$ is not a constant.. That is the main issue.. Other wise I could have used integrator..

Comment: For constant *K* (in the sense of [constant function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_function)) you’d use exponential map. There is no great difficulty to rewrite the d.e. into quaternionic form, if you make the reasoning backwards. First, remember your favorite “vector *v*” and write *R v* = *q v q*‌*, where *q* is an arbitrary versor and “\*” means q.conjugation, then differentiate it by *q* at *q* = 1: d(*R v*) = *dq v* + *v* (*dq*)*. Now apply q.multiplication explicitly to components of *v, dq* and rewrite the diff-al as a matrix-by-*v*. What do you see in the matrix?

Comment: I didt get would you write in answer section..